# Thinking Sphinx result all results when with condition is an empty array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

I have a case where in I need to filter all products based on search and within a category if the customer chooses one.

1. If the customer chooses all and enters a search keyword, I need to find all products matching that keyword within all Subcategories of that category.
2. If the customer chooses a particular category and enters a keyword ,

   1. It should display all products matching keyword ,if found , within subcategories of that category
   2. Else it should not display anything.

I'm using thinking sphinx here.

```
cat_ids = 1

sub_cat_ids = SubCategory.where("category_id = ? " , cat_ids).collect(&:id)

products = Product.search  "@(name,description) #{txt_srch}", :match_mode => :extended  , :with => { :sub_category_id => sub_cat_ids } , :per_page => 54 ,:page => page
```

If a user enters `txt_srch = shoes` and suppose the sub_cat_id is `[]`. Then sphinx will return all products(under all categories) matching that keyword.

I was expecting it not to return anything since the sub_cat_id is `[]`.

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :product, :with => :active_record do



 # fields

  indexes description, :sortable => true 

  indexes name    

  has sub_category_id

end
```

Comment: A trivial solution might be to populate `sub_cat_ids` with one invalid id if it results empty from the query:



`sub_cat_ids = SubCategory.where("category_id = ? " , cat_ids).collect(&:id)
sub_cat_ids = [-1] if sub_cat_ids.empty?`

Have a try and let me know if it works...

Comment: Andrea's idea is a good one - but better to go with 0 (Sphinx integer arrays are unsigned).

Comment: Ya that works. I was doing that! There isn't any other way I suppose. Thank you all :)